# Core Data: NSFetchedResultsController sorting by date vs. ordered to-many relationship

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data

I am writing a demo messaging app to learn Core Data. In my model, an entity `Conversation` has a to-many relationship `messages` to `Message`. A `Message` has a `timeStamp`. I intend to display these messages in a collection view/table view with an `NSFetchedResultsController`. I want to know what would be the most efficient way to sort these messages. I searched around and found that I could sort the messages using:

- an `NSSortDescriptor` on `message.timeStamp`
- making the `messages` relationship ordered
- adding a `sequence` property to `message`

What should be the best way to sort the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort order should reflect your application logic:
is it logical to move messages inside a conversation? (if yes, sort by sequence number)
Do you want your data to be displayed chronologically? (if yes, sort by `timeStamp`)

in any case I wouldn't use the ordered relationship as a sort order as you would probably want an FRC to display your data in a table view, and he will manage memory and changes for you.
In addition to that you would want to batch fetch this relationship in any case and not simply let your table view datasource be the ordered set relationship (which will cause the items to be fetch one by one).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then I believe sorting on `timeStamp` would be appropriate.